# Is there a built-in function that acts like strcat from the string start?

Tags: c++, c, string

I have a string that I want to encircle with quotes.

What I have so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char my_str[100] = {0};
    strcat(my_str, "hello world!");
    strcat(my_str, "\"");
    strcat(strrev(my_str), "\"");   // I want a simpler way for this
    strrev(my_str);                 // and this (though it isn't that complicated...)
    printf("%s", my_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (as expected) is "hello world!"

Is there a simpler way, or a built-in function that does this?

*PS. An answer in C++ (that handles C-strings) would be fine too*

Comment: Yes, there is: [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class template.

Comment: Since you didn't say it explicitly (always do!) I guess your output should be `"hello world!"`?

Comment: @user3121023 Need to do it for existing strings

Comment: Yes, you can use `sprintf`: `sprintf(my_str, "\"%s\"", "hello world!"); printf("%s", my_str);`

Comment: @Ron did you mean `insert` with `pos = 0`?

Comment: @CIsForCookies Prefer string to character arrays in C++. The `std::string` has the necessary facilities for manipulating strings.

Comment: Is it [tag:c] or [tag:c++]? Don't tag both because they are distinct languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you can use the overloaded `+` operator for strings.

```
std::string my_str;
... // here you calculate the contents of my_str
my_str = "\"" + my_str + "\"";
```

---

If you are obliged to use a `char` array for some reason, you should convert it to a `string` first:

```
char my_str[100];
... // here you calculate the contents of my_str
auto new_my_str = "\"" + std::string(my_str) + "\"";
```

Here, either the first or the second string should be a C++ string (i.e. `std::string` and not a `char` array), to make the overloaded operator work.

In C++14, you can use a string literal to make the first string the correct type, using the `s` suffix:

```
char my_str[100];
... // here you calculate the contents of my_str
auto new_my_str = "\""s + my_str + "\"";
```

---

If you also want your output in the same `char` array, use `c_str` and `strcpy` on the resulting C++ string. You can even fit it into one line of code:

```
char my_str[100];
... // here you calculate the contents of my_str
strcpy(my_str, ("\""s + my_str + "\"").c_str());
```

This code is vulnerable to buffer overflow, unlike all the previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the source array already contains a string. Otherwise you could build the string in quotes very easy from scratch.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[100] = "Hello World";

    size_t n = strlen( s );

    memmove( s + 1, s, n );

    s[0] = '\"';

    s[n+1] = '\"';
    s[n+2] = '\0';

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"Hello World"
```

In C++ if to use the template class std::string then the same task can be done the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "Hello World" );

    s.reserve( s.size() + 2 );

    s.insert( 0, 1, '\"' );
    s += '\"';

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise if you deal with a character array that contains a string then the approach will be the same as it is shown for C.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. Just start with a string that holds the opening quote:

```
char my_str[100] = "\"";
strcat(my_str, "Hello, world!");
strcat(my_str, "\"");
```

Or, if you don't want to initialize the string that way, just copy the opening quote:

```
char my_str[100];
strcpy(my_str, "\"");
strcat(my_str, "Hello, world!");
strcat(my_str, "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a built-in function that acts like strcat from the string start?

Yes, it is called `strcat`. What you would do in the normal case, is simply to create a second string:

```
char arr1[N] = "hello world";
char* use_this = arr1;

puts(use_this);

char arr2[N] = "\"";
strcat(arr2, use_this);
use_this = arr2;

strcat(use_this "\"");

puts(use_this);
```

Trying to be "smart" and save memory by doing this in-place is probably not a good idea, since it comes at the expense of execution speed.

As a side note, your code won't compile on a standard C compiler, because there is no function called "strrev" in the C language. It is a non-standard extension and should therefore be avoided.

Comment: I preferred to not use temporary variables as it seems neater from my perspective. That said, using `strcat` (without reversing the string) won't be possible. Thanks about the `strrev` comment - I found it here (http://c-language.com/c-tutorial/c-string/c-strrev/) and though it was standard

Comment: "seems neater" is a poor rationale. Focus on writing efficient and readable code. Also, http://c-language.com seems to be a proper crap site... chapter 1, "The Turbo C++ IDE"...

Comment: "Yes, it is called `strcat`" should be "No, but you don't need it anyway", shouldn't it?

Comment: @Gerhardh No, my point is that strcat at the start of the string, is `strcat` with parameter 1 and 2 switched.

Answer (score -1):

There is an easier way - just shift the existing string the required amount of space to make room for the string you want to prepend. Since the source and target areas of memory are overlapping you can't use `strcpy` or `memcpy`, but instead have to use `memmove`

```
memmove(my_str+1,my_str,strlen(my_str)+1);
```

and then replace the first character with the double quote.

```
my_str[0]='\"';
```

Comment: You just (possibly, it's undefined behavior) left your string without a `NUL` terminator; moving `strlen` covered the characters, but not the `NUL`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: `my_str` is initialized with null characters in OP‘s code. As long as the manipulated strings do not fill the buffer, they will be null terminated. This code might not conform to common patterns for good practice, but it is not wrong.

Comment: The code would indeed be more rugged if changed to `memmove(my_str+1,my_str,strlen(my_str)+1);`.

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I made such a rookie mistake...fixed it now though